# Ant JUnit task report on the version of the JUnit jar used (e.g. Junit 3, 3.8, 4)

Tags: java, ant, junit

Since, during execution of the Ant [JUnit](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html)  task, the JUnit jar may be picked up from various places, is there any way to get Ant to report on the console the version of JUnit used for running the tests or even the exact jar used?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried declaring this import:

```
import junit.runner.Version;
```

and then calling this somewhere in your code?

```
Version.id();
```

Then, print this value to the console.

Comment: I like this as a hack, although one would likely agonize over the paralyzing question of which JUnit test to place this code into.

Comment: Isn't this just a one-time thing so you know what version you are running? JUnit has nothing to do with your code; the idea is that it steps out of the way.

Comment: Why not create a test specifically to print out the JUnit version?